# Potential energy in a magnetic field + Lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Just like a charge has some sort of potential energy in an electric field, I'm sure it does in a magnetic field to, since both fields are essentially the same thing from different points of view. How does one mathematically deduce the potential energy of a charge/conductor in a magnetic field?

Also, how would one go about finding the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian of said system in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm sure it does in a magnetic field to, since both fields are essentially the same thing from different points of view.

They are not "the same thing from different points of view". They are both part of the same thing, electromagnetic field. But they are different, independent parts.

> How does one mathematically deduce the potential energy of a charge/conductor in a magnetic field?

One does not, because magnetic force is not a conservative force.

Conservative force is such a force that is at every position in space a gradient of some function of position; this function value is so-called potential energy at that position.

Non-conservative force is such a force that cannot be expressed as a gradient of any function of position. Magnetic force $q\mathbf v\times \mathbf B$ is one such force; it has, in general, non-zero curl and thus is not a gradient of any function of position, and potential energy cannot be defined.

Comment: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_15.html See equation 15.20

Comment: That explains the concept of potential energy of magnetic moment, or circuit, in external magnetic field, and also magnetic energy of system of electric currents. It is not about potential energy of a single charged particle in magnetic field. The latter does not exist.

Comment: But electric currents are made of electric point charges, don't they?

Comment: Yes. This does not mean concept describing relation of large set of moving charges translates to analogous concept describing single charge.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to recall that force is defined as the negative derivative of the potential energy. Now since the force magnetic fields induce on a charge is given by the Lorentz force:

$$\vec F_{M} = q \hskip0.1cm \vec v \times\vec B$$

what we need is a term to add to the free-particle lagrangian $\mathcal L_{M}$ such that:

$$\nabla \mathcal L_{M} = -\vec F_{M} = - \frac{d\vec p}{dt}$$

however if such term would include velocities in a let's say linear fashion (hindsight provided) our requirement must be modified to address the fact that the Euler-Lagrange equations would also be shifted by such a term. This is because the canonical momentum ($p_i = \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial v_i}$) gets shifted by this linear velocity term in the lagrangian. So the actual recipe for the term to add to the lagrangian is modified slightly to:

$$\nabla \mathcal L_{M} = -\frac{d\vec p}{dt} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal L_M}{\partial \vec v}$$

Ok so now that we know what we are looking for we can start the algebra part.
Instead of the field it is better to use the vector potential $\vec A$ to express the energy:

$$\vec B = \nabla \times\vec A  \hskip 1cm \Rightarrow \hskip 1cm B_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j A_k$$

which we will introduce in the expression of the Magnetic force:

$$F_{M,i} = q v_j \epsilon_{ijk}B_k = q v_i \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}\partial_lA_m$$

here is where some Levi-Civita algebra comes in handy, namely:

$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm} = \delta_{jl}\delta_{km} - \delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}$$

and thus:

$$ F_{M,i} = q v_j (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{lj}) \partial_l A_m = \partial_i(q v_j A_j) - q \partial_j(v_j A_i)$$

The first term in this expression is the potential energy, the second term is a bit more complicated, first of all it is technically two terms since:

$$\partial_j(v_j A_i) = \frac{d A_i}{dt} - \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial t}$$

The first one represents a correction to the canonical momentum of a particle in a generic electromagnetic field, the second (as you correctly pointed out) is the force due to the fact that a generic magnetic field induces an electric field. So we should ignore it since it is electric and not magnetic in nature.

$$\frac{d\vec p}{dt} + q\frac{d\vec A}{dt} = \frac{d( \vec p + q \vec A) }{dt} = \nabla (q \hskip 0.1cm \vec v\cdot \vec A) $$

This means that:

$$\mathcal L_M=-q\vec v\cdot \vec A$$

We need to check that this is consistent, in other words we need to check if the term we needed to add to the kinematical momentum is really $\frac{\partial \mathcal L_M}{\partial \vec v}$, but this is trivially true.

So in summary there is a well defined lagrangian that reproduces magnetic forces but this lagrangian, and more paticularly its potential terms belongs to a more general class of potentials, meaning potentials which are velocity dependent. See for example: Jackson Ch. 12, [Feynman](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_15.html) Eq. 15.20 (where we have to make use of the fact that the current assciated with a point charge is $\vec j(y) = q \vec v \delta^{(3)}(x-y)$ where $x$ is the position of the charge)

Comment: But you have just demonstrated why magnetic force *is not* a gradient of $U_M$.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean, if what bothers you is that there is a new canonical momentum, please recall that momentum is the derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to velocity. The correction I just mentioned is there because the magnetic energy term is velocity dependent and thus it shifts the canonical momentum.

Comment: I mean $q\mathbf v \times \mathbf B \neq \nabla (q\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf A)$.

Comment: Oh I see what bothers you, that I should have called it $\mathcal L_M$?

Comment: You can call it anything, magnetic force is not a conservative force. There is no potential function. There is Lagrangian that describes magnetic force, but this Lagrangian does not imply there is "magnetic energy".

Comment: Right, so no lagrangian?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138592/discussion-between-diogenes-figueroa-and-jan-lalinsky).